# Workflow Manager Configuration Internal Error Occurred

Tags: workflow-manager

I have been following this guide -
https://collab365.community/configuring-sharepoint-2013-to-support-workflow-management/

To enable SP2013 workflows within SP Designer. (within my SP2016 farm)

When I try to complete Step 23, I get the following error message -
[image]

I ran Get-WFfarm to confirm I'm using the correct WorkflowHostUri.

I have checked my bindings in IIS and all looks as though it should do.

When I try to view the XML in browser, I get -
"An internal error occurred" there as well.

Troubleshooting guides appear to be few and far between online, but those I have found, I have tried.

Has anyone else had the same issue?
Or does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on the cause of the error, however, I have now resolved the issue by following 2 guides -

Uninstalling Workflow Manager -
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34424.sharepoint-2016-uninstall-the-workflow-manager-1-0.aspx

And then found a guide that actually worked for me -
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx

Both guides from the same source. Big thank you to Waqas for putting those together.